# Disable ligatures/kerning on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, typesetting

With HTML5 canvas experiments on Mozilla show that:

```
measureText("TEXT,") < measureText("T") + measureText("E") + measureText("X")+measureText("T")+measureText(",")
```

Browser is adjusting letters to reduce size of text. I can avoid this mode by adding \u200b between letters, as you can see in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gxt4q97u/ But this hack doesn't work with fillText. How can I draw text on canvas, so text width is sum of widths of characters. Is there anything else rather then drawing char by char, which is too slow?

Comment: What browser are you seeing the issue on? Firefox only?